# truffle migrate --network rinkeby: Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown

Tags: truffle

All works with the local testrpc instance.

Now trying to deploy to rinkeby via the Infura site using the HDWalletProvider.
Everything looks trivially configured... (unless I need to specifically unlock an account?)

But the migration doesn't work, failing on the `1_initial_migration.js` which is a tiny contract.

```
 > truffle migrate --network rinkeby 
Using network 'rinkeby'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
exceeds block gas limit
 >
```

Anyone else see / resolve this ?

Comment: I think this errors happens when you have configured in truffle.json a gas value larger than the network gas limit (or the default used by truffle is larger).

Answer (score 1):

1. My gas setting in truffle.js:

   gas: 4300000     //may be 21000 - 3000000

   gasPrice: 20000000000
2. Your smart contract maybe a little complicated, cost more gas than setting, please kindly check and increase the `"gasLimit"` of genesis.json, the largest number can be 0xffffffff.
3. by the way, if you need mining in your ethereum node, set the difficulty of genesis.json a little low, for example "0x2000". Otherwise, it is easy to exceed time.

Hope it can help you.